Downloading all webmaps in my organization
I want to download all the webmaps in my organization as Portal Web Maps .pitemx.
And save them them in r"C:\Main\Content\fadi\Portal Web Maps. Only the folder members are exported without the portal We Maps .pitemx
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import os


org_url = "https://mylink.maps.arcgis.com/"  
username = "username"  
password = "password"  
gis = GIS(org_url, username, password)

save_location = r"C:\\Main\\Content\\fadi\\Portal Web Maps"
os.makedirs(save_location, exist_ok=True)

def download_web_maps_for_member(user, save_dir):
    """
    Download all web maps for a specific user.
    :param user: ArcGIS Online user object
    :param save_dir: Directory to save the .pitemx files
    """
    os.makedirs(save_dir, exist_ok=True)
    print(f"Processing user: {user.username}")

  
    user_items = user.items()
    web_maps = [item for item in user_items if item.type == "Web Map"]

    if not web_maps:
        print(f"No web maps found for user: {user.username}")
        return

    for web_map in web_maps:
        print(f"Downloading web map: {web_map.title}")
        # Export web map to .pitemx
        try:
            export_item = web_map.export(title=web_map.title, export_format="ArcGIS Pro Map")
            export_path = os.path.join(save_dir, f"{web_map.title}.pitemx")
            export_item.download(save_path=save_dir)
            print(f"Web map '{web_map.title}' saved to {export_path}")
            export_item.delete()  # Clean up temporary export item
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Failed to download web map '{web_map.title}': {e}")


users = gis.users.search(query="*", max_users=1000)


for user in users:
    user_folder = os.path.join(save_location, user.username)
    download_web_maps_for_member(user, user_folder)

print("Download process completed!")


Please [Edit] your Question to state the problem you have encountered. It's not fair to those who would help you to provide a large block of code to debug without a clear indication of what might be wrong. At a minimum, you should include the output generated by your print statements.
